# Why POST request in @WebMvcTest returns 403 with permitAll()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-test

I'm testing a controller that has a POST mapping. Here is the exctract:

```java
@RequestMapping(path = "/bookForm", method = POST)
public String saveBook(@Valid @ModelAttribute(name = "book") BookCommand bookCommand,
                       BindingResult bindingResult) {
        // blah blah

        return "redirect:/books";
    }
```

I'm playing with Spring security, so I wrote a test where I expect that some of my `GET` mappings will be rejected for unauthorized user, but for this POST method I wanted to permit all.

Here is a test config class:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityTestConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/books/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/bookForm").permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

The thing is, that `mockMvc` still returns 4xx for a POST call. Why is that?

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = BookController.class)
@Import(SecurityTestConfig.class)
public class BookControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    // ... mocks ect


    @Test // <- this is ok
    public void shouldNotAllowBookUpdate() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/books/1/update")).andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());
    }

    @Test // <- this fails
    public void shouldAllowFormHandling() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/bookForm")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use only one Mapping Annotation `either @PostMapping(value="...") OR @RequestMapping(value="...",method=POST)`. Also do the following changes in `TestConfig`

---

```
http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/bookFrom").permitAll()  
         .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Comment: Yes, this `csrf().disable()` did the trick. I'm accepting and voting up your answer. :)